# Unable to connect to MySQL server container from APS .NET app from container

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, docker-compose

#### I am learning docker and want to use docker-compose to run MySQL db and ASP .NET app but i cannot connect them while using docker-compose.

Code below:

DbContext file:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Data;

namespace DockerLearning.Models
{
    public class DbContextModel : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=172.18.0.2;database=;uid=root;pwd=pass;port=3306;");
        }
    }
}
```

How i try to test it:

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<string> databases = new List<string>();
            using (var dbContext = new DbContextModel())
            {
                var connection = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
                ViewData["Databases"] = null;
                ViewData["Error"] = null;
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        string query = "SHOW DATABASES;";
                        using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, (MySqlConnection)connection))
                        {
                            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    databases.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                                }
                                ViewData["Databases"] = databases;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                        ViewData["Error"] = ex.ToString();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }              
                return View();
        }
```

View:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        @if (ViewData["Databases"] != null)
        {
            @foreach (var db in (List<string>)ViewData["Databases"])
            {
                <li>@db</li>
            }
        }else{
            <p>@ViewData["Error"]</p>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerLearning.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./DockerLearning.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "DockerLearning.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerLearning.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerLearning.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.4"

networks:
  backend:

services:
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: mysql
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
    networks:
     - backend
  website:
    image: dockerlearning
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    networks:
        - backend
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    depends_on:
      - database
```

Error:

```
System.TimeoutException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, MyNetworkStream& networkStream) at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, MyNetworkStream& networkStream) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() at DockerLearning.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in /src/Controllers/HomeController.cs:line 31
```

I was able to connect them both using separate containers. When i run them using `docker-compose up -d`, both container can ping each other and seems git gut. If i install mysql, on web app container i can connect to it using `mysql -u root -p -h 172.18.0.2 -P 3306` , and it works fine. Problem arises when i try do do that from code in this app. I don't understand what i am doing wrong since it works while not using docker-compose.

Comment: The networks syntax seems not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested with specify network aliases as connectionstring works well using docker compose on your sample.

```
optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=mysqlcontainer;database=;user=root;password=123456", new MySqlServerVersion(new Version()));
```

```
version: "3.4"

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

services:
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: mysql
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - mysqlcontainer
  website:
    image: dockerlearning
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    networks:
      backend:
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    depends_on:
      - database
```